# Adding Nodes to Existing XML

Tags: php, xml, append, edit, nodes

The problem i was having is the Root XML was being produced every time it writes to the XML. 
The Main issue was setting up Child and Defining the Root. From the help of Łza
I now understand the Root XML Node is ignored. 
So then you setup and create a Child and then add your content, And example of the correct format is.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('FILENAME.xml');  // Load XML File Need to add IF Statment to create if does not exist

$result = $xml->addchild('Result'); // Ignore Root NODE and Add Child Results

$result->addChild('Time', gmdate('D-M-Y -H:i:s')); // Rest of the below adds Child to Result and outputs results
$result->addChild('Channel', $Site);
$result->addChild('Type', '**');
$result->addChild('Process', $Status);
$result->addChild('SKU', $code->SKU);
$result->addChild('item', $item);
$result->addChild('Status', '$Feedback');
$result->addChild('ErrorID', '$Error');
$result->addChild('Message', '$Message');

$xml->asXml('FILENAME.xml');  //Write to file would be

// All of the above Code is using variables from another part of the script
```

The output would be

```
<Root>
    <Result>
        <Time>Fri-May-2013 -09:15:22</Time>
        <Channel>20</Channel>
        <Type>**</Type>
        <Process>Update</Process>
        <SKU>98746524765</SKU>
        <Item/>
        <Status>Problem</Status>
        <ErrorID>999-Error</ErrorID>
        <Message>Unknown file format support</Message>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <Time>Fri-May-2013 -09:15:22</Time>
        <Channel>20</Channel>
        <Type>**</Type>
        <Process>Update</Process>
        <SKU>5412254785</SKU>
        <Item/>
        <Status>Problem</Status>
        <ErrorID>123-Error</ErrorID>
        <Message>Invalid Item</Message>
    </Result>
</Root>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to add new node `<results>` under `<data>` node? Because you also has one another node called `<Result>`. Is there difference between them?

Comment: Sorry that is my own silly Mistake, I want <Result> to go into the <data> node. I will edit the original Post sorry.

Comment: Can you briefly explain what exactly you want? Do your code not working as you have code it? Or you have any error on it?

Comment: The code runs Fine. The problem is There is two results in the XML
And each time it write to the XML it opens and closes the TAGS with <data> </data>
I want at the Start of the XML to show <data> and the last entire in the XML to show </data> 
The current code Writes in one error, opens and closes the Tags <data> Then does it again for each time it writes to the XML. 
If you have a look at the XML Results, Remove the </data> and <data> from the middle of the XML data, and thats the format i am after. 
Child <Result> to data each time it writes to the XML.

Comment: Ok. Because when first I seen your XML then I had doubt on it that why `<data>` is being repeated again. It should be document node.

Comment: Can you also show your sample `DHError.xml` with small data? And what about `$product`? From where it is generated? Can you show your other code which you had used?

Comment: The code goes over about 20 PHP files this is just part of a include statement for error generating. its for posting data and pulling data, DHError.xml is posted above, that is the output of the current script in the XML Format.  
The Script works fine, Just the:
</data>
<data>
does not need to be there, It just needs to be there once at the start and once at the end.
Each time the script runs and it has a error with Files, It will update the XML with the records effected. Again output of the XML is above, Just copied and pasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use SimpleXMLElement library instead hardcoded xml creation. This is maybe more complicate to use at the begining, but much more safe (I mean avoid possible errors in xml structure when you hardcode the xml) and easy to use when you just get start to use it. 
And easy to add/remove nodes, childnodes.

This is an example for your code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

$data = $xml->addChild('data');
$result = $data->addChild('Result');
$result->addChild('Time', gmdate('D-M-Y -H:i:s'));
$result->addChild('Channel', $SiteID);

// ... and the same way create all your xml nodes.
// if you want add next <result> node witch all elements repeat the code, (or put it in loop if you want more <result> elements):
$result = $data->addChild('Result');
$result->addChild('Time', gmdate('D-M-Y -H:i:s'));
$result->addChild('Channel', $SiteID);

// and after create all nodes save the file:
$xml->asXml('DHError.xml');
```

above code will create xml:

```
 <xml>
  <data>
   <Result>
     <Time>Fri-May-2013 -12:14:39</Time> 
     <Channel>data</Channel> 
   </Result>
   <Result>
     <Time>Fri-May-2013 -12:14:39</Time> 
     <Channel>data</Channel> 
   </Result>
  </data>
 </xml>
```

Thats it. Then if you need to load and process the xml it would be easy:

To load the File simply use:

```
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file('DHError.xml');

// to add new node <Result>:
$resultNext = $xml2->data->addchild('Result');
$resultNext->addChild('Time', gmdate('D-M-Y -H:i:s'));
$resultNext->addChild('Channel', $SiteID);

//and save file
$xml2->asXml('DHError.xml');
```

this create a xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
 <xml>
  <data>
   <Result>
     <Time>Fri-May-2013 -12:27:24</Time> 
     <Channel>data</Channel> 
   </Result>
   <Result>
     <Time>Fri-May-2013 -12:27:24</Time> 
     <Channel>data</Channel> 
  </Result>
  <Result>
    <Time>Fri-May-2013 -12:27:24</Time> 
    <Channel>data</Channel> 
  </Result>
 </data>
</xml>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, 
I have used the Load statement and it works perfect. 
So i just need to add a IF XML Exists Load if not Create :-) 
A much easier way of doing it than the method i was attempting. Works perfect Thank you very much